# Flutter проблема с запуском build_runner после перехода на Dart 3

Tags: flutter

Все было хорошо пока не обновился :)

В логах следующая ошибка:

```
PS D:\Repositories\Flutter\market-zdorovie> dart run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
Building package executable... 
Failed to build build_runner:build_runner:
/C:/Users/%D0%A0%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/watcher-1.0.2/lib/src/constructable_file_system_event.dart:7:57: Error: The class 'FileSystemEvent' can't be extended, implemented, or mixed in outside of its library because it's a sealed class.
abstract class _ConstructableFileSystemEvent implements FileSystemEvent {
```

в pubspec  environment не поменял

```
environment:
   sdk: '>=2.18.6 <3.0.0'
```

Подскажите, что случилось c build_runner ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете старую версию watcher, несовместимую с вашим Flutter SDK. Просто запустите `flutter pub upgrade`, чтобы обновить его до более новой версии. У меня та же ошибка, и обновление до версии 1.1.0 у меня работает.

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст ответа (нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа) на русский язык

Comment: Огромаднейшее спасибо